# Odd behavior when fetching 100K rows from MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, large-data-volumes

Looking for some ideas here... I have a MySQL table that has 100K rows of test data in it.

I am using a PHP script to fetch rows out of that table, and in this test case, the script is fetching all 100,000 rows (doing some profiling and optimization for large datasets).

I connect to the DB, and execute an unbuffered query:

```
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT * FROM TestTable", $connection) or die('Errant query:  ' . $query);
```

Then I iterate over the results with:

```
if ($result) {
    while($tweet = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ctr++;

        if ($ctr > $kMAX_RECORDS) {
            $masterCount += $ctr;
            processResults($results);
            $results = array();
            $ctr = 1;
        }

        $results[] = array('tweet' => $tweet);
    }

    echo "<p/>FINISHED GATHERING RESULTS";
}

function processResults($resultSet) {
    echo "<br/>PROCESSED " . count($resultSet) . " RECORDS";
}
```

$kMAX_RECORDS = 40000 right now, so I would expect to see output like:

> PROCESSED 40000 RECORDS
>  PROCESSED 40000 RECORDS
>  PROCESSED
>   20000 RECORDS
>  
>  FINISHED GATHERING RESULTS

However, I am consistently seeing:

> PROCESSED 39999 RECORDS
>   PROCESSED 40000 RECORDS
>   
>   FINISHED GATHERING RESULTS

If I add the output of $ctr right after $ctr++, I get the full 100K records, so it seems to me to be some sort of timing issue or problem with fetching the data from the back-end with MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC.

On a related note, the code in the while loop is there because prior to breaking up the $results array like this the while loop would just fall over at around 45000 records (same place every time).  Is this due to a setting somewhere that I have missed?

Thanks for any input... just need some thoughts on where to look for the answer to this.

Cheers!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the question?  I don't need the pedantic comments, but rather some insight into the issue being raised.

Comment: Not really, hence its a comment not an answer. It's not pedantic (or not meant to be), there is some interesting reading there that I thought may help. Take it or leave it its up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start going through your result `$ctr` has no value and doing first incrementation will evaluate it to 0. But when reaching `$kMAX_RECORDS` you reset it to 1 instead of 0. I don't know however why you see 1 row less in the first time of calling `processResults()`. I think it should be one more.

As to missing last 20000 rows notice that you are running `processResults()` only after `$ctr` exceeds `$kMAX_RECORDS`

Comment: Thanks Zefiryn, got the counter problems squared away, and now getting expected results.  Any ideas on why the while loop would just fall over after 45000 or so records?

Comment: @Raconteur You could be hitting [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) or [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: Cheers, vasco, will check those out.

Comment: memory_limit @ 128M, max_execution_time = 60.  It falls over after about 10s, and always at the 42563rd record (which has no special characteristics), which is around 6MB in the array.

Comment: try setting ini_set('display_errors', 1); and see if there are any errors reporting. Or look into error logs

Answer (score 1):

You're building an array of results, and counting that new array's members. So yes, it is expected behavior that after fetching the first row, you'll get "1 result", then "2 results", etc...

If you want to get the total number of rows expected, you'll need to use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Comment: Aren't you missing the obligatory scolding for using mysql_?  lol :)

Comment: No, I don't bother to harp on that. If you know what you're doing, writing with the mysql_ functions is as safe (or even safer) than using pdo/mysqli.

Comment: I'm with you brother....as well as that other standard "You need to redesign everything you've ever done on everything you've got to do it the right way", lol

Comment: @MarcB To get mysql_* style code on the same level of security as, for example, PDO, would take *tons* of code. Furthermore, the mysql_* functions are explicitly discouraged from being used on php.net, and have already been subject to numerous talks of imminent deprecation. Promoting use of those functions is not a good idea, regardless of how you feel their security compares to more modern APIs.

Comment: Yes, well, the mysql_ functions are going to be Windows XP of PHP - hangling on farrrrrr past when they should've been executed. there's just too much code out there depending on it. And using PDO is absolutely no guarantee of writing "safe" queries. An idiot can inject themselves just as badly with PDO as they can with any other DB interface.

Comment: No, not missing any scolding.  :)  This is some down-and-dirty testing, not production code.  Although, even in a production situation I will generally roll my own DBI.

Comment: @Raconteur Testing using something completely different from what you are actually going to use is not testing at all.  This is a very poor excuse for using mysql_*.